# Error: The `libsass` binding was not found

Tags: linux, git, node.js

Возникла ошибка:

```
  Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in /home/biba/project/wmg/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-11/binding.node
    This usually happens because your node version has changed.
    Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current node version.
        at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (/home/biba/project/wmg/node_modules/node-sass/lib/extensions.js:158:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/biba/project/wmg/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:16:36)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/biba/project/wmg/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:186:21)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

node -v
v5.6.0
npm gulp-sass -v
3.8.1
```

Ошибка:

```
Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in /home/biba/project/wmg/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/**linux-x64-11**/binding.node
```

а в папке **node-sass/vendor/** лежит папка **linux-x64-47**
После ребилда ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачал нужный файл с репозитория и вручную скопировал

Comment: Это решение или уточнение подробностей вопроса?

Comment: Это решение, после долгих мучений. Если есть лучше, то пишите!